# using variables in rel attribute in jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using the rel attribute to match a div to a button.  I use the button's id in the corresponding div's rel field.  There are multiple buttons. When a button is clicked I want to show the corresponding div with the show() method, and to hide the other divs.  The buttons work fine, but the divs are not responding. My gut says I'm not formatting the selector properly. Thanks.

```
    $("div.media_button").click(function (){

   var relid = this.id;

   $("div.media_button").not(this).fadeTo("normal",0.33);
   $(this).fadeTo("normal",1);
   $("div.media_selection[rel!='" + relid + "']").hide();
   $("div.media_selection[rel='" + relid + "']").show();   
 });
```

Answer (score 15):

You do not need the single quotes. Can you paste the markup just incase the below doesnt end up working.

```
$("div.media_selection[rel=" + relid + "]").hide();
$("div.media_selection[rel=" + relid + "]").show();
```

Comment: That shouldn't be the problem though, quotes won't break the selector, they're just not needed. Welcome to 10k btw!

Comment: ty karim, it was a shot in the dar...I have seen the quotes screw things up before, as I mentioned the markup would help!

Comment: Bet you the button ID does not exactly match the div rel attributes :)

Comment: :) yup..that is the odds on fav

Comment: That being said, are **div[rel='abc'].media_selection** and **div.media_selection[rel='abc']** treated the same way by jQuery?