# Click on document.ready

Tags: jquery, click, document-ready

I have a page filtered using links' rel= attributes. I'm trying to get document.ready filter it based on the first link's rel= attribute and instead it loads all the links.

If my hacked-together code isn't enough of an indication, I'm pretty new to jQuery. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('.port-cat a:first').click(function(evt){    
        var clicked_first = jQuery(this).attr('rel');

        jQuery('#portfolio .post').hide();
        jQuery('#portfolio .' + clicked_first).fadeIn(400);
    })
});
```

As requested: here's my HTML in a nutshell, with $new_tags pull tags and placing as link rel= attributes like this:

```
<a href="#" rel="web">Web</a>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="portfolio">

<span class="port-cat"><?php echo $new_tags; ?></span>
```

Comment: You should also post your html as reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a class selector on the rel attribute:

```
jQuery('#portfolio .' + clicked_first).fadeIn(400);
```

Instead, you want to do this:

```
jQuery('a[rel=' + clicked_first + ']).fadeIn(400);
```

But I suspect this isn't the real answer to your problem. It would be helpful to see your html or have a better description of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @Drew. So what are you trying to do? What part of the html is the `.hide()` and `.fadeIn()` working on?

Comment: The page is rendering post thumbnails based on tags. The filter bar lets users click links to filter those posts by tag, therefore .hide() and .fadeIn(). What I'm trying to do, is override the behavior of showing all then filtering. I want it to be filtered on page load.

Comment: OK, so this rel tag's value...'web'...how will you be using that to find the specific post you want? I know this is your first question, but in order to help you, we need to know all aspects of the problem. Right now, I can't tell how you want to select these posts, so I have a hard time telling you what selectors to use.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the rel attribute to clicked_first, and then calling it back as a class. Here is an example of how to call by rel attribute: [using variables in rel attribute in jquery selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322198/using-variables-in-rel-attribute-in-jquery-selector)